# ERROR: Teradata prepare: Syntax error when usign date format 'ddmmyyy'd in SAS

Tags: date, unicode, sas, teradata

I'm using this code to extract information from this database. However, it is showing me this error:

> ERROR: Teradata prepare: Syntax error, expected something like ')' between a string or a Unicode character literal and the word
> 'd'. SQL statement was: WITH vmher102ult as ( select cod_cte, max(fec_consulta) as max_fec_consulta from
> klarmxpw_her.vmher102 where cod_cte not in ('','0','00000000') and fec_consulta>='01MAR2021'd group by cod_cte) select t1.*
> from klarmxpw_her.vmher101 as t1 inner join vmher102ult as t2 on t1.cod_cte=t2.cod_cte and
> t1.fec_consulta=t2.max_fec_consulta.

The code I'm using for this pass through is the following:

```
proc sql;
connect to teradata as tera (user=&tuser. password=&tpass. server='TDMX03');
    create table vmher101_m as 
        select * from connection to tera (
            WITH vmher102ult as (
            select cod_cte, max(fec_consulta) as max_fec_consulta
                from klarmxpw_her.vmher102
                    where cod_cte not in ('','0','00000000') 
                    and fec_consulta>='01MAR2021'd
                    group by cod_cte)
    select t1.* 
        from klarmxpw_her.vmher101 as t1
        inner join vmher102ult as t2 
        on t1.cod_cte=t2.cod_cte and t1.fec_consulta=t2.max_fec_consulta);
disconnect from ter;
```

Does anybody know what can I do?

Comment: `and fec_consulta>='01MAR2021'd` - this is not valid Teradata SQL.  Are your dates really stored as a string like that? ddMMMyyyy.

Comment: Yes. They are stored like that. I will try using fc_consulta >= DATE '2021-03-01'. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If they're really stored that way, you'll want to convert it to an actual date - `and to_date(fec_consulta, 'DDMONYYYY') >= DATE '2021-03-01'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TERADATA code inside the () after `from connection to tera`.

Try

```
and fec_consulta>= DATE '2021-03-01'
```

[Teradata Documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Data-Types-and-Literals/June-2017/Data-Literals/Date-Literals)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this way.